# Why the total product price in the shopping cart does not include the different product options selected?

Tags: magento-1.8, price, addtocart

Here is the issue that happened since my Magento installation has been restored.
The shopping cart should normally include all the product options selected but since the restoration, only the product price is showing.

I put some screenshots below:

First screenshot is the product detail page, showing the Frame and its related price:
[image: Frame price]

When you click on "Add to cart", it gets you through the product options selection process as you can see below. Price at the top shows 55$, which is the Frame value.

[image: Step 1: Prescription]

Once you click on "Next" you get into the Lens type selection, as shown on the next screen:

[image]

Price is updated after selecting "Transition Lenses", and is now including the price of this option as shown on the following screenshot:
[image]

On the following screenshot I selected an option for Saturation, and the price is now showing 225$, including this last option.
[image: Lens Options section]

I get into the shopping cart page after clicking on "Add to Cart". As you can see on the next picture the prices related to product options selected are not included in the total price. Price in shopping cart only considers the Frame price.
[image: Product options not considered in shopping cart]

It was working correctly before I had to restore the Magento backup.There may be a conflict somewhere in my Magento.
Does anyone have a solution for this issue?  Which file(s) should I actually check in my Magento installation?

Thanks for your help.

Cheers,

Comment: Magento version ?

Comment: Hi Shorabh. It's running on Magento 1.8.1.0.

Comment: Hi, anyone has an idea about the cause of this pricing issue?